# Replace ID with string in SQL view - without join

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a table with `ID` and few other columns. Because it has only 3 rows and I know who each  `ID` belongs to, there was no need for me to add column with `name`. Now I am in SQL View, I am printing the contents and just out of curiosity I would like to add the names **without** a joining table.

**Is it possible?** I am using SQLite, but a proof of concept is enough, regardless the database.

What I have:

```
id col1 col2 ...
1    10   21
2    85   45
3    43   32
```

What I want to see:

```
id name col1 col2 ...
1  "ab"   10   21
2  "cd"   85   45
3  "ef"   43   32
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `case`:

```
select (case when id = 1 then 'ab'
             when id = 2 then 'cd'
             when id = 3 then 'ef'
        end) as name, col1, col2
from . . .
```

Comment: Thanks! Just a question, is it possible doing another way? Temporary database, enum or something? Though, it wouldn't save any typing, right.. (SQLite vs other db)

Comment: SQLite doesn't support enum.  Why would you want a temporary database?  And the question specifically says you don't want to do a `join`.